# PHP Datatables Queries

Tags: php, jquery, postgresql, datatables

I just started using the jQuery/PHP datatables plugin. I can perform some queries easily e.g

```
$dt = new DataTables();
$dt->setTable(array(
            'select' => 'n.request_id, n.type_name, n.request_date, n.initiator, n.target_customer, n.agent_number, n.merchant_number, n.bill_reference, n.amount',
            'from' => 'approvals n'
        ));
$dt->andWhere("n.customer_id", "{$_SESSION['customer_id']}");
```

What I'm wondering is how to perform some more queries e.g. passing the SQL OR statement or even passing a PHP array to be used in the WHERE statement for comparison, like I'd do in SQL like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 3, 6)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=3 OR id=4
```

Comment: I think `WHERE id=3 OR id=4` is same as `WHERE id IN (3, 4)`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes they are actually the same but I need to put that in the datatables format as above.

Comment: What library you are using for server side processing?

Comment: @Ravi not so sure since I picked up some work...any other way I can help?

Comment: you can read `DataTables` class and it's function. may be there are functions like `$dt->orWhere` or `$dt->orWhere_In`. take a look into source code of library

Comment: Already did that...those ain't there.